# PyQt6 program crashes when using two TreeView delegates

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, crash, delegates, pyqt6

I've prepared a minimal reproducible example of this problem. There are two `TreeView` delegates: one for checkboxes and one for progress bars. If I add any one of these delegates, but not the other one, the program doesn't crash. But if I add both, it crashes (upon trying to show the rows and the delegates). It gives the Segmentation Fault error when crashing.

`delegates.py`

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QPoint, QRect
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui


class CheckBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning QCheckBox cell of the column to which it's applied.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        """
        Important, otherwise an editor is created if the user clicks in this cell.
        """
        return None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        checked = bool(index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole))
        check_box_style_option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        if (index.flags() & Qt.ItemIsEditable):
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled
        else:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_ReadOnly
        if checked:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
        else:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
        check_box_style_option.rect = self.getCheckBoxRect(option)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_CheckBox, check_box_style_option, painter)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if not (index.flags() & Qt.ItemIsEditable):
            return False
        # Do not change the checkbox-state
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease or event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            if event.button() != Qt.LeftButton or not self.getCheckBoxRect(option).contains(event.pos()):
                return False
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                return True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() != Qt.Key_Space and event.key() != Qt.Key_Select:
                return False
        else:
            return False
        # Change the checkbox-state
        self.setModelData(None, model, index)
        return True

    def getCheckBoxRect(self, option):
        check_box_style_option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        check_box_rect = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_CheckBoxIndicator, check_box_style_option, None)
        check_box_point = QPoint (option.rect.x() +
                                option.rect.width() / 2 -
                                check_box_rect.width() / 2,
                                option.rect.y() +
                                option.rect.height() / 2 -
                                check_box_rect.height() / 2)
        return QRect(check_box_point, check_box_rect.size())

    def setModelData (self, editor, model, index):
        newValue = not bool(index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole))
        model.setData(index, newValue, Qt.EditRole)


class ProgressBarDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # Get the data for the item
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)

        # Draw the progress bar
        painter.save()
        rect = option.rect
        rect.setWidth(int(rect.width() * progress))
        painter.fillRect(rect, QtGui.QColor("#00c0ff"))
        painter.restore()
```

`mainwindow.py`

```
from ui_form import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL, Slot
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from delegates import CheckBoxDelegate, ProgressBarDelegate


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.row_data = []
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exit)

    def reinit_model(self):
        self.model.clear()
        self.rootItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Checkbox', 'Title', 'Progress'])
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(self.model)

    def get_row_data(self):
        row_data = []
        for i in range(3):
            title = f"Col 1 Row {i}"
            row_data.append([title])
        return row_data

    def reset_row_data(self):
        self.row_data.clear()
        self.row_data = self.get_row_data()

    class Show_list(QThread):
        def __init__(self, AppWindow):
            QThread.__init__(self)
            self.AppWindow = AppWindow

        def run(self):
            self.AppWindow.reset_row_data()

    def populate_window_list(self):
        self.reinit_model()
        for title_link in self.row_data:
            item = [QtGui.QStandardItem(),
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(title_link[0]),
                    QtGui.QStandardItem()]
            progress = 0.5
            item[2].setData(progress, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)
            self.rootItem.appendRow(item)
        self.ui.treeView.show()
        cb_delegate = CheckBoxDelegate()
        pb_delegate = ProgressBarDelegate()
        self.ui.treeView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, cb_delegate)
        # self.ui.treeView.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, pb_delegate)
        for i in range(3):
            self.ui.treeView.resizeColumnToContents(i)

    @Slot()
    def show_list(self):
        self.thread = self.Show_list(self)
        self.connect(self.thread, SIGNAL("finished()"),
                     self.populate_window_list)
        self.thread.start()

    def exit(self):
        QApplication.quit()
```

`main.py`

```
import sys
from mainwindow import MainWindow
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.reinit_model()
    getRowDataButton = widget.ui.getRowDataButton
    getRowDataButton.clicked.connect(widget.show_list)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Kf3itP3a)'s also `ui_form.py`.

I've tried to add `cb_delegate.deleteLater()` and `pb_delegate.deleteLater()`, but it didn't help. The program loaded the list and crashed immediately.

Comment: Change to `cb_delegate = CheckBoxDelegate(self.ui.treeView)` and `pb_delegate = ProgressBarDelegate(self.ui.treeView)`. Also, the `self.connect()` syntax is obsolete, use `self.thread.finished.connect(self.populate_window_list)`. Finally, you should avoid accessing and modifying objects from external threads if they are potentially being accessed in the main thread too. Use signals for that.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot, this works! Your comment looks like it's worth being a full answer.